# Laravel use IF clause on MySQL column

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

How can I use MySQL `IF` on a column using Laravel? How can I optimize the following query to use Laravel's model or Query builder? Right now I'm using a raw query.

```
$contacts = ['88544','22455','66981']

DB::select('SELECT name, 
IF(file_path=null OR file_path=\'\',\'\',CONCAT("' . url("/media") . "/\",file_path)) AS profile_pic_url FROM users 
LEFT JOIN file_uploads on file_id=file_uploads.id WHERE 
(phone_number IN('" . implode("','", $contacts) . "') 
OR phone_number_full IN('" . implode("','", $contacts) . "')) ORDER BY name ASC");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this and see if it works

```
    DB::table('users')
    ->select('name')
    ->selectRaw(IF(file_path=null OR file_path=\'\',\'\',CONCAT("' . url("/media") . "/\",file_path)) AS profile_pic_url)
    ->join('file_uploads', 'file_id','=','file_uploads.id')
    ->whereRaw(phone_number IN('" . implode("','", $contacts) . "') 
    OR phone_number_full IN('" . implode("','", $contacts) . "'))
    ->orderBy('name', 'asc')
```